# posix システムにてパスワードを生成するには?

Tags: shellscript, posix

posix 規格に対してポータブルな、パスワード生成シェルスクリプトはどのようなものになりますか? パスワードは、ひとまずアルファベット(大文字・小文字)+数字で生成できればいいと考えています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

乱数の生成には `awk` の `rand()` が使えます。
ただ、種の決定をどうするのがよいのか、自信がないです。
[Directory Structure and Devices](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html) に `/dev/urandom` は無いですし、[date](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html)コマンドでナノ秒などを取得することもできないようです。
とりあえず以下では、秒までの時間とプロセスIDを使っています。

```sh
#!/bin/sh
seed=$(( $(date +%y%j%H%M%S) + $$))

awk -v seed="$seed" -f - <<__AWK__
BEGIN{
    len = 20
    chars = "1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    srand(seed)
    chars_num = length(chars)
    for (i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        c = int(rand() * chars_num) + 1
        printf("%s", substr(chars, c, 1))
    }
    printf("\n")
}
__AWK__
```

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/urandom` を利用するのが手っ取り早いかと思います。

```
#!/bin/sh
# Usage: ./mkpassword.sh [SET] [LENGTH]

SET=${1:-"A-Z-a-z0-9"}
LENGTH=${2:-32}
tr -dc "$SET" < /dev/urandom | head --bytes "$LENGTH"
echo
```

使用例

```
$ ./mkpassword.sh
PQ8gRtyfQ7lo2OL7ftqpkdKZXV3kSaej
```

Comment: `/dev/urandom` は POSIX で定められているのですか？

Answer (score 0):

Perlスクリプトにはなりますが、こんなコードを使用しています。

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

$passwd_char = '1234567890' . 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' . 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$len = 8;
$passwd = "";
$size = length($passwd_char);
for($n = 0; $n < $len; $n++) {
  $passwd .= substr($passwd_char, int(rand($size)), 1);
}
print "$passwd\n";
```